# Why is there white smoke coming from the exhaust where the tailpipe and muffler meet and it looses power it is a 2000 Mazda626 234000+ miles

Tags: mazda, smoke, mazda-626

White smoke from exhaust where tailpipe and muffler meet and it looses power it is a 2000 Mazda 626 with 234000+ miles

Comment: This is a very broad question. There are so many things it could be, from a bad gasket to a bad head gasket allowing coolant into to the exhaust. The two things may or may not be related. Can you add more details about the problem?

Comment: White smoke usually indicates a coolant leak into a cylinder. This is usually caused by a blown head gasket, but there are usually other ways as well. Definitely not a good thing.

Comment: Muffler is clogged?